# How to perform operations on dates in queries?

Tags: sql, date, hsqldb, libreoffice-base

I'd like to add 100 days to a field in a query:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD("date" + INTERVAL '100' DAY) FROM "history";
```

or whatever… but it doesn't work with the default HSQLDB frontend…

Any workaround ?

Comment: I am using LibreOffice V 4.1.2.3, maybe I can't do this because of a bug. The field type of "date" is DATE. Does it have to be TIMESTAMP or DATETIME ?

Comment: Well, it is apparently not possible with HSQLDB versions below 2.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default HSQLDB version in OpenOffic and LO is 1.8. It does not supports this function.

HSQLDB version 2.x supports several functions and expressions for date / time arithmetic.

If the column is named "date", this form is also supported. Note there is no underscore in the function name:

```
SELECT DATEADD('day',100, "date") FROM "history";
```

Comment: Using an outdated HSQLDB… sorry…

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the date_add(), just add the interval to the column:

```
SELECT "date" + INTERVAL '100' DAY
FROM "history";
```

Comment: @BogeyJammer: apparently you are using an outdated version of HSQLDB then

Comment: Right… I've just checked the version embedded in LibO 4.1: v1.8. Sad…